# To take Advantage of Multi-Processor in Node.js, why the number of clusters we fork is CPU cores count?

Tags: node.js, express, operating-system, v8

I know maybe it's a stupid question. I'm not good at OS knowledge.

Usually the number of cluster/process we fork is the CPU cores count, like the [Nodejs offical Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) display.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

**But I'm confused what if we fork the cluster more than the number of CPU cores, what it gonna happen?**

Is it the empirical value, best practice or any other reason?

Answer (score 3):

> But I'm confused what if we fork the cluster more than the number of CPU cores, what it gonna happen?

Nothing will happen, everything will still work, but putting more than one CPU-intensive thread or process per core will not make the application any faster - if anything, it may only make is slower because the core will waste some portion of the time on the context switches between the threads.

If you have CPU-bound operations then the optimal number of threads/processes per core is always 1. For I/O-bound operations it shouldn't really matter as most of the time the processes will not do any computations anyway.

Comment: This is interesting. I wonder if there is still an application to using more forks than cores if you have blocking code?  given that each fork has iẗ́s own event loop, could there be some benefit in reducing the impact of blocking code on other requests?

Answer (score 0):

Think about an ideal situation wherein all what you run in your system is node based application server.

This is not practical, as there would be a minimum of 5-10 processes running in your machine to house-keep your system environment.

Also assume that the event loop thread (aka application thread, aka main thread) is the one which performs the most useful work in the node.js process.

Again, this is not true, as there are few helper threads in node.js process to house-keep the asynchronous event-driven programming model.

Again assume that the throughput of your server measured through the eyes of connected clients is a direct function of how each process is able to avail free CPUs, and all the actions performed by the process as part of the request-response cycle is purely CPU bound.

This may or may not be TRUE. If the server has further connections with external servers such as DBs, web services etc. they gets initiated in the I/O channel, and the thread goes ahead and address some other request. But due to the fact all the I/O operations are made non-blocking, and all potential blocking operations are made asynchronous, the main thread will be relatively running only CPU bound actions, with only one blocking call in the whole circuit - the polling function which blocks when there is no ready I/O.

Cluster module suggests to use # of CPUs for the cluster member count, the above hypothetical scenario is assumed, and it gives relatively optimal performance, in the absence of any better and comprehensive reasoning.

Hope this helps.